# determine s3 bucket public access

Tags: amazon-s3

Currently AWS displays/flags "Public" label when a bucket is open to public. I would like to get this information via an API as opposed to looking at the aws s3 console.

Is there any API to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GET Bucket acl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETacl.html) rest method.  Not sure on your language of choice, but here's a javascript example.  See the [javascript sdk s3.getBucketAcl documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getBucketAcl-property)

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME',
};
s3.getBucketAcl(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) 
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      else
        console.log(data);
});
```

This returns the response in my test example as:

```
{
  "Owner": {
    "DisplayName": "",
    "ID": ""
  },
  "Grants": [
    {
      "Grantee": {
        "Type": "Group",
        "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
      },
      "Permission": "READ"
    },
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the AllUsers group have READ access therefore this is a public readonly-s3 bucket I configured via the console.

Comment: Thanks. However this will only tell if bucket is public through ACL configuration. one can also make the bucket public through bucket policy. How do we capture that information through an API?  I can parse the policy and find it but was looking for an API since AWS already determines this and showing this in the console.

Comment: Sorry that detail wasn't clear, I'm not as familiar with policy but seems there's comparable methods for [GET bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETpolicy.html) or if you prefer here's the js sdk docs for [s3.getBucketPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getBucketPolicy-property)

Comment: I see what you mean now, that kind of convenience method to parse and return the public status from the policy would likely live on the sdk if it did exist.  I'm not seeing anything in the JS SDK so you might need to do the parsing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bucket with no such "AllUsers" URI, but is still shown in the console as "public access". There must be multiple methods of allowing public access.